# European Time in get-date

Tags: powershell

I'm using following command to get the current date and time and to convert it into a format where it can be used to write the filename of export files.

```
$DateTime = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd-hhmmss')
```

It would return something like this: 20150801-030811. Is there a way to get the european timeformat 0:00 to 23:59 instead of the 0:00am, 11:59pm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HH` instead of `hh` for 24 hour time format:

```
$DateTime = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd-HHmmss')
```

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.